# Recommendation for ML algorithm to differentiate between ban or allowance

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to Machine Learning and wanted to see if any of you could recommend an algorithm I could apply onto a project I'm doing. Basically I want to scrape popular housing websites and look at their descriptions to see if they allow/disallow something, for example pets. The problem is a simple search for pets leads contradictory results: 'pets allowed' and 'no additional cost for pets' or 'no pets' or 'I don't accept at this time'. As seen from these examples, often negative keywords 'no' are used to indicate pets are allowed, whereas positive keywords like 'accept' are used to indicate a ban. As such, I was wondering if there was any algorithm I could use (preferably in python) differentiate between the two. (Note: I can't run training data to generate an algorithm myself as the thing I am actually looking for is quite niche).

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow!! Firstly, it is kinda doable, but I don't know if it is possible without training. The first thing you should do in your project is scrapping the websites you want to retrieve information from. The majority of this websites are structured in a way that informations like this are located in particular sections. Then you should analyze if your problem can be solved with regex, which could be a great alternative if the information is proper structured.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for is "document classification".  This is a document classification problem.  You start with documents (i.e. webpages) and you want to classify them as "allows pets" or "doesn't allow pets" (or whatever).  There are a [lot](https://realpython.com/python-keras-text-classification/) of good [tutorials](https://www.opencodez.com/how-to-guide/text-classification-using-keras.htm) out there for performing document classification but a full explanation is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

You won't be able to do this for your particular niche case without providing at least some training data but you could gather, say 30 example websites, extract their text, manually add labels ("does fit my niche" vs "doesn't fit my niche"), and then run through a standard document classification system and see if that gets you the accuracy you want.  Also in order for this to work with a small amount of training data (like your 30 documents), you'll need to start from a [pretrained model](https://realpython.com/python-keras-text-classification/#using-pretrained-word-embeddings).

Good luck!